# Is there a way to hide unique identifier of Linear Segmented Colormap object?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colorbar, colormap

I am trying to write a function that visualizes a color bar in a subplot, accidentally stuck with a unique identifier problem! The way I want to write a function is to have a colorbar and two additional subplots. The code for the Linear Segmented Colormap is given below.

I am running the python file from command prompt. The output is popped up as a window. I want this function to work as jupyter (.ipynb) and as script file (.py) too.

```
def cb(fig, ax, cmap):
    cmap = cm.get_cmap(cmap)

    norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=1, vmax=5)
    bounds = [i for i in range(5 + 1)]
    fig.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap),
                 cax=ax, orientation='horizontal', label=cmap, ticks=bounds)
    ax.plot()
```

The above function is for creating a subplot of colorbar in a segmented view. The below code is for creating a plot grid.

```
def color_bar(cmap):
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.set_figheight(6)
    fig.set_figwidth(6)

    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid(shape=(2, 2), loc=(0, 0), colspan=2)
    ax2 = plt.subplot2grid(shape=(2, 2), loc=(1, 0), colspan=1)
    ax3 = plt.subplot2grid(shape=(2, 2), loc=(1, 1), colspan=1)

    x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
    y = np.cos(x)

    cb(fig, ax1, cmap)
    ax1.set_title('ax1')
    ax2.plot(x, y)
    ax2.set_title('ax2')
    ax3.plot(x, y)
    ax3.set_title('ax3')

    plt.tight_layout()


color_bar("copper")
plt.show();
```

The output of the following code contains the unique identifier of the linear segmented colormap, How to hide that linear segmented colormap identifier?

[image: Output]

Hope experts could help me!
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am running the python file from command prompt. The output is popped up as a window. I hope that gives the view. I want this function to work as jupyter (.ipynb) and as script file (.py) too.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment--it was not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this call

```
    fig.colorbar(mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap),
                 cax=ax, orientation='horizontal', label=cmap, ticks=bounds)
```

you have `label=cmap`.  So the label becomes `str(cmap)`, which is not want you want. Change that argument to the desired label, or remove that argument if you don't want a label on the colorbar.